# I have a micro controller whose specifications state operating voltage from 2.3v to 5.5V

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, supercapacitor

Does this mean my input has to be in this range or can it be higher?

Comment: What makes you think it could be higher?

Comment: Answer is in the datasheet.  Question should be closed.

Comment: OPERATING voltage range is min to max. Usually you'd use eg 5.0V or 3.3V (being standard supply values). Vdd = Vcc = supply voltage must lie inside stated range.

Comment: @LeonHeller Datasheets can be overwhelming at first. An answer could be very useful. That said, the question would be received better if it asked "Where can I find the input voltage ranges in the datasheet of my micro?".

Answer (score 1):

Input rating can be independent of supply rating, e.g. it is possible for a 3.3V device to have 5V-tolerant inputs, such as is the case with STM32F103x8/B MCUs. You will need to read further into the datasheet in order to find out what input voltages are safe to use with it.

But in general clamping diodes will usually keep the input within 0.3V of the supply voltages, so even if you can use higher input voltages don't expect to be able to maintain that voltage outside the chip.